# failed to elevate privilege to enable mode, at prompt [b'Huawei>'] with error: unable to check privilege level

Tags: ansible

Hi I am trying to run a basic playbook for huawei router. It is basically to display current-configuration.

My playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Master node
  hosts: huawei_node

  vars:
    max_retries: 4

  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: configurations of VRRP
    block:

    - name: get device homename
      ansible.netcommon.cli_command:
        command: "display current-configuration"
        check_all: true
      register: hostname

    - name: Display result to terminal window
      debug:
        var: hostname.stdout_lines
```

The result im getting:

```yaml
PLAY [Master node] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [get device homename] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [huawei_node]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "failed to elevate privilege to enable mode, at prompt [b'Huawei>'] with error: unable to check privilege level [^\nError: Unrecognized command found at '^' position.]"}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
huawei_node                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The output should be showing the command is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because I am defining ansible_network_os=ios for this huawei device. It should be ansible_network_os=community.network.ce.